# weird format output when i print a memory address in c

Tags: c, windows, gcc

When I try this C code that prints the memory address of three variables:

```
int a = 45;
float b;
char c;

printf("Address of a: %p \n", &a);
printf("Address of b: %p \n", &b);
printf("Address of c: %p \n", &c);
```

The output is :

```
Address of a: 0061FEB4
Address of b: 0061FEB0
Address of c: 0061FEAF
```

and I want it on the format like `0x7ffd3d518618`. How can I do it?

I have executed the same code on a another computer under Ubuntu and the output shows in the format of `0x7ffd3d518618`.

Comment: Is the computer in the shown case a 32-bit machine? Because those addresses are clearly shorter than the ones on the Ubuntu system, so probably a 32 vs 64 bit thing.

Comment: That probably means that you are excuting your code in a 32-bit machine instead of a 64-bit machine.

Comment: no the computer is a 64 bit machine

Comment: @Berok you can run 32 bit code on a 64 bit machine. The fact that the addresses are shown with 8 hexadecimal digits tells me that your code is most likely running in 32 bit mode. Please tell us what OS/IDE/compiler/version/etc. you're using. Your C code is correct.

Comment: i don't use a ide i use gcc 8.2.0 to compile the code on a windows machine

Comment: @Berok Your program is certainly compiled as 32 bit program on Windows for whatever reason (you don't supply the appropriate compiler flags, your compiler is a 32 bit only compiler who knows). What does `gcc -v` report?

Comment: Are you using mingw or cygwin? If so, 32 bit or 64 bit versions?

Comment: gcc -v report : Thread model: win32, Target: mingw32. ok so how can i change it to be 64 bit i just have to reinstall it ?

Comment: Yes, there are 64-bit versions that you should install if you want 64-bit support.

Comment: @Berok google "mingw64"

Comment: ok thank you, for your help

Comment: Just to make sure... your issue is that the addresses are "too short", right? Because that's what all commenters so far seem to have assumed. If instead your issue is the missing "0x" or the upper-case characters, then 32 vs 64 bit has nothing to do with that

Comment: i have installed mingw64 and now if a recompile the code it now output 000000000065FD98 for the memory address how can i have it on the format 0x now ?

Comment: @FelixG your right my issue is the missing 0x a the beginning of the address, do you have a solution ?

Comment: Well, the problem is that the output of %p is *implementation defined*, which means that different compilers might produce different results. So, if you need the format to be exactly the same accross multiple platforms, things might get a little tricky (because using %x wouldn't be a good option either, since that is not supposed to be used with pointers)

Comment: so what can i do ?

Comment: If the code is supposed to be portable, without hardcoding any assumptions about the compiler and/or c-library ... honestly my best idea right now would be to do a `snprintf("%p", NULL)` at the start of your application, check if it begins with "0x", and then depending on that use either "%p" or "0x%p". I wouldn't actually recommend to do this, but at least it would be portable code. The easier option (which _**should**_ work for _**most**_ platforms) would be to cast the pointer to `uint64_t` and use `%#llx` as format specifier (# means you want the "0x" in front)

Comment: the thing i don't undurstand is that on all other device the address return is like 0x7ffd3d518618 but this is the first time it return this format for a address. is there a way to print again address like this. ps: a pointer in c++ returned this address 0x65fb4c

Comment: As i said, the output is implementation defined, so even printing it as binary or decimal would still be conforming (as would be pretty much any other format you can or can't think of). The reason your other devices all use the same format might be because they use the same C library.